# HTTP POST request via Wininet

Tags: c++, http, visual-c++, wininet

In **VC++**, I am trying to send an HTTP POST request and get its response.

I have the below code, which compiles successfully, yet fails to POST.

First I try to send the POST request to the request bin for testing purpose

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    static CHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    static CHAR frmdata[] = "name=John+Doe&userid=hithere&other=P%26Q";

    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpenA("MyAgent", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession "pipedream.com", 8733, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnect, "POST", "/r/enj77inn26shk", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
```

Then read the response using

```
    DWORD dwContentLen;
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(dwContentLen);
    if (HttpQueryInfo(hRequest,
                  HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
                  (LPVOID)&dwContentLen,
                  &dwBufLen,
                  0))
    {
        char *pData = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, dwContentLen + 1);
        DWORD dwReadSize = dwContentLen / 10;   // We will read 10% of data
                                            // with each read.

        DWORD cReadCount;
        DWORD dwBytesRead;
        char *pCopyPtr = pData;
        for (cReadCount = 0; cReadCount < 10; cReadCount++)
        {
            InternetReadFile(hRequest, pCopyPtr, dwReadSize, &dwBytesRead);
            pCopyPtr = pCopyPtr + dwBytesRead;
        }
        // extra read to account for integer division round off
        InternetReadFile(hRequest,
                     pCopyPtr,
                     dwContentLen - (pCopyPtr - pData),
                     &dwBytesRead);
        // Null terminate data
        pData[dwContentLen] = 0;
        std::cout << pData << std::endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The endpoint I'm posting to

[image]

Comment: The second parameter of `InternetConnect` is just the host name, not the URL. Drop `https://` part.

Comment: You say you want to make a POST request, yet you pass `"GET"` to `HttpOpenRequest`. The second parameter of `HttpOpenRequest` is the path - the part that comes after the host name; not the URL. Pass `"/"` there. You need to pass `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` in the `flags` parameter if you want to connect via HTTPS.

Comment: More generally, add error handling. I expect most of your API calls fail.

Comment: The headers you pass to `HttpSendRequestA()` are missing required trailing line breaks, you are passing 2 `Content-Type` headers instead of 1, and you need to use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()`: `static CHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"; ... HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), ...);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau , still no luck, please see the edited version. does it hv sth to do with the URL?

Comment: @epiphany you are connecting to `pipedream.com` on port 8733 when you should be using port 443 instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, thx for pointing that out, turns out I've use the wrong method, I can send post request now, Thank you u all for yr help